# Having trouble with space glitch inside custom HTML line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a line that visually separates my content for my web page.
However I am having this problem which I didn't have before.
This is a line on my page that's not broken

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqxx5.png

And this is a line on my page that has the same CSS and html(exact same) but it looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUtTA.png

As you can see that the difference is the weird space in between the borders which I don't want.

Here is the html

```
<div class="line"></div>
```

And here is the css

```
.line{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border:2px solid #bd983d;
    color: #bd983d;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

I haven't been able to fix the problem as it appears sometimes and then disappears
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried checking for the element properties with Developer Tools in your browser? On Firefox, right-click the line and then click "Inspect Element (Q)". That opens a view where you can see if the properties are exactly same. On the right side of the view, there is a "Box Model" section that shows border,margin,padding and other properties.

Comment: Yeah i've checked and all the properties are exactly the same. Fortunately I've fixed it with the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it depends on the content inside that line or sometimes it depends on the users' resolution or browser or even the zoom-in state. It's tricky but the easiest solution here is to just use `border-top`.

```css
.line{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #bd983d;
    color: #bd983d;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: @BaekhanSung you're welcome, please accept this as the answer if it did help. Thanks!